# Get the sum of all carried digits while performing addition on 2 or more integers

Tags: php, math, sum, integer-arithmetic

I've got this task, which I honestly don't understand what exactly to do.
It my be because of my English level, or mathmatics level, but this is really something I can not make sense of. Could you help be at least to understand the task ?
My php knowledge is very well, at least I thought so...

**The task is this :**

"Carry" is a term of an elementary arithmetic. It's a digit that you transfer to column with higher significant digits when adding numbers.

This task is about getting the sum of all carried digits.

You will receive an array of two numbers, like in the example. The function should return the sum of all carried digits.

```
function carry($arr) {
    // ...
}

carry([123, 456]); // 0

carry([555, 555]); // 3 (carry 1 from ones column, carry 1 from tens column, carry 1 from hundreds column)

carry([123, 594]); // 1 (carry 1 from tens column)
```

Support of arbitrary number of operands will be a plus:

```
carry([123, 123, 804]); // 2 (carry 1 from ones column, carry 1, carry 1 from hundreds column)
```

Comment: Well, where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do

Comment: Well it was actually really easy to do. Just a misunderstanding of Math terms since English is not my native language. Thanks to @Sammith , I managed to write the code needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background information on "carry": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)

For this task, we don't actually need the numbers written under the equals line, just the numbers which are carried.  Importantly, the carried numbers need to be used when calculating subsequent columns.

Before looping each column of integers, reverse the order of the columns so that looping from left-to-right also iterates the lowest unit column and progresses to higher unit columns (ones, then tens, then hundreds, etc).

For flexibility, my snippet is designed to handle numbers of dynamic length.  If processing potential float numbers, you could merely multiply all number by a power of 10 to convert all values to integers.  My snippet is not designed to handled signed integers.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5X6hr))

```
function sumCarries(array $array) {
    $columns = ['carries' => []];

    // prepare matrix of 1-digit integers in columns -- ones, tens, hundreds, etc
    foreach ($array as $integer) {
        $columns[] = str_split(strrev($integer));
    }

    // sum column values in ascending order and populate carry values
    // subsequent column sums need to include carried value
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen(max($array)); $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $columns['carries'][$i + 1] = (int)(array_sum(array_column($columns, $i)) / 10);
    }

    // sum all populated carry values
    return array_sum($columns['carries']);
}

$tests = [
    [123, 456], // no carries in any column
    [555, 555], // 1 ones, 1 tens, 1 hundreds
    [123, 594], // 1 tens
    [123, 123, 804], // 1 ones, 1 hundreds
    [99, 9, 99, 99, 99], // 4 ones, 4 hundreds
    [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9], // 10 ones
];

var_export(array_map('sumCarries', $tests));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 2,
  4 => 8,
  5 => 10,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's homework, I'm not going to fully answer the question, but explain the pieces you seem confused about so that you can put them together.

```
            1       11      111      111  <- these are the carry digits
  555      555      555      555      555
+ 555 -> + 555 -> + 555 -> + 555 -> + 555
-----    -----    -----    -----    -----
             0       10      110     1110
```

For a better example of two digits, let's use `6+6`. To get the carry digit you can use the [modulus operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) where `12 % 10 == 2`. So, `(12 - (12 % 10)) / 10 == 1`.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Programming instructors frequently ask bizarre questions like this that have virtually no practical application beyond the fact that there's no earthly reason for anyone to want to do this, so there's not a `get_carry_digit_sum()` library function that does it for you.

Comment: I feel this question is going to be very Unclear to the majority of readers.  I ony understood what the OP wants after reading your answer -- this is a symptom of a bad question.  It would be better if you edited the question to clarify the task.  Then only answer the question (completely) after the OP made a coding attempt.

Comment: @mickmackusa honestly virtually every part of this post rides the line of being flagged/closed, and If I could have crammed a suitable example into a comment I would have. That said, the question asked was not necessarily about how to solve the homework question, but in understanding the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again. @Sammitch

I got it to make it work. Actually the problem was my English Math Level. The term "Carry digits" had no meaning at all for me. I was completely focusing on something else.

Here is my code : It may be far from perfect, but it does the job :)

```
function carry($arr) {
    
    $sum_ones = 0;
    $sum_tens = 0;
    $sum_hunds = 0;
    $arrCount = count($arr);
    
    foreach($arr as $key){
        
        $stri = (string)$key;
        
               $foo[] = array(
                "hunds" => $stri[0],
                "tens" => $stri[1],
                "ones" => $stri[2]
                    );
            
    }
    
    $fooCount = count($foo);
    
    for($i=0; $i<$fooCount; $i++) {
        $sum_ones+= $foo[$i]["ones"];
        $sum_tens+= $foo[$i]["tens"];
        $sum_hunds+= $foo[$i]["hunds"];

    }
        $sum1 = ($sum_ones - ($sum_ones % 10)) / 10;
        $sum10 = ($sum_tens - ($sum_tens % 10)) / 10;
        $sum100 = ($sum_hunds - ($sum_hunds % 10)) / 10;
    
        return ($sum1 + $sum10 + $sum100);

        }

    $arr = array(555, 515, 111);

    echo carry($arr);
```